# How to Ask User for Confirmation: Shell

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, confirmation

I am new to shell, and my code takes two arguments from the user. I would like to confirm their arguments before running the rest of the code. I would like a y for yes to prompt the code, and if they type n for no, then the code will ask again for new arguments

Pretty much, if i type anything when I am asked to confirm, the rest of the code runs anyways. I tried inserting the rest of the code after the first then statement, but that didn't work either. I have also checked my code with ShellCheck and it all appears to be legal syntax. Any advice?

```
#!/bin/bash

#user passes two arguments 
echo "Enter source file name, and the number of copies: "

read -p "Your file name is $1 and the number of copies is $2. Press Y for yes N for no " -n 1 -r
echo  
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
echo "cloning files...."
fi


#----------------------------------------REST OF CODE

DIR="."

function list_files()
 {
 if ! test -d "$1" 
 then echo "$1"; return;
 fi

 cd ... || $1
 echo; echo "$(pwd)":; #Display Directory name

for i in *
do
if test -d "$i" #if dictionary
then 
list_files "$i" #recursively list files
 cd ..
 else
 echo "$i"; #Display File name
fi

done
}

 if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then list_files .
exit 0
fi

for i in "$@*"
do
DIR=$1 
list_files "$DIR"
shift 1 #To read next directory/file name
done
if [ ! -f "$1" ]                        
then
echo "File $1 does not exist"
exit 1
fi

for ((i=0; i<$2; i++))
do
cp "$1" "$1$i.txt"; #copies the file i amount of times, and creates new files with names that increment by 1
 done

status=$?                                  
if [ "$status" -eq 0 ]
then
echo 'File copied succeaful'
else
echo 'Problem copying'
fi
```

Comment: I tried your code and got `code.tio: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token \`then'`

Comment: `echo   if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]` the `echo` shouldn't be there (and it explains the error @melpomene mentions : it's not an if/elif/else construct anymore, it's an `echo` command followed by a `then` that isn't associated with any `if`)

Comment: @Aaron .... I'm still a tad confused. I put that echo before the if statement so that the rest of the output could be printed on the next line. I removed it anyways, and the code still runs despite the user's input for confirmation

Comment: Err yes that makes sense, only the `echo "cloning files...."` is inside the `then` block, the rest is executed unconditionnaly. Either invert the condition and make it `exit` when the `$REPLY` doesn't match `[Yy]`, or put the whole rest of the script inside the `then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the prompts into a `while` loop might help here.  The loop will re-prompt for the values until the user confirms them.  Upon confirmation, the target code will be executed and the `break` statement will terminate the loop.

```
while :
do
  echo "Enter source file name:"
  read source_file

  echo "Number of copies"
  read number_of_copies

  echo "Your file name is $source_file and the number of copies is $number_of_copies."
  read -p "Press Y for yes N for no " -n 1 -r
  if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
    echo "cloning files...."
    break ### <<<---- terminate the loop
  fi
  echo ""
done

#----------------------------------------REST OF CODE
```

Comment: Sorry, to bother again, but if a user types "N" then the code continues to promt the user with  echo "Your file name is $source_file and the number of copies is $number_of_copies." Is there a way to break out of that loop?

Comment: Usually, CTRL+C.  If you're on a Mac, it might be something else. Command + period/dot (.) ? You could also change the `while :` to `while [[ ! "$REPLY" =~ [Xx] ]];` and the confirmation prompt to `"Press Y for yes N for no X to exit"`.  Then, the user can reply to that prompt with "X" or "x" to terminate the program..